Azure Function or Background Service[Background tasks with hosted services] which is more cost affective?
I have some requirements for using some back ground process.
I  have 2 option #

Time Trigger Function
Background Service [Background tasks with hosted services]

which one is more cost affective?
I have referred Link for azure function
and back ground service LINK
any suggestion on this

Choosing the Azure Functions or Container Apps for background services depends on various factors including the nature of the workload, performance requirements, scalability needs, and cost considerations.
In Simple terms, if your background tasks are event-triggered, short-lived, and have unpredictable or intermittent execution patterns - then Azure Functions may be a cost-effective solution and easier to manage because the cost is based on execution time and resource consumption (execution units).


As you can see in the above function app, it uses a consumption hosting model where the cost is incurred in outbound data transfer but not on the execution count and time.
If you visit the Azure Functions Hosting Models and Pricing Page where especially the Consumption plan is free of cost to 1 million requests and 4 Lakh GB per second of execution time it is cost-minimized solution for event-driven triggers, workloads but it will have cold start overhead if the background tasks are invoked infrequently.
Azure Container Apps might be better if you have long-running tasks or require more control over the underlying infrastructure. Here you will be deploying containerized applications that can handle heavier workloads compared to serverless functions.
It means Azure container apps are good for background services with high-performance requirements whereas Azure functions with premium or dedicated hosting plans can also give high performance and you can stop the Azure service if you are not using it for a specific time period to reduce cost.
As I said in the 1st line of my answer, you must consider multiple factors such as Infrastructure management like control over resources and environment, scale on demand, timeout limitations, short-lived or long-running process type, etc.
